# Server code is not listening properly, when making it to loop infinitely

Tags: c, sockets, unix, ftp

So this is my college project, efficiency of usage of variables in not that of a big issue.
Program is "**FTP - File transfer**" based on **Socket network programing in Unix** environment! This programs just responds only to **one** service.

This program let you to download file from client to server
And download from server to client!
My code is working upwrite with validation, but the problem occurs when i try to loop the execution of server infinitely, as restarting server every time of execution is meaningless!

Can anyone suggest me where the logical error happening?.

**Server Side:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>     
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h> 


    int sockfd,newsockfd,portno,clien;
    char buffer[256] = { '\0' };
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
    int n;
    int download();
    void upload();
    void server_files();
    void authentication();
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {


    if(argc<2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error, No port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sockfd<0)
    {
        printf("Error opening socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));//zeroing the sturture

    portno =atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) <0 )
    {
        printf("Error on binding\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int optval;
    setsockopt(100,sockfd, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);


    listen(sockfd,5);
    clien = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1)
    {
    newsockfd=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clien );


    if(newsockfd <0)
    {   
        printf("Error on accept\n");
        exit(1);
    }   


    //Authentication
    char auth[2];
    read(newsockfd,auth,2);
    int x = atoi(auth);
    if(x==0)
    {
        char user[20]={ '\0' } ;
        char pass[20]={ '\0' } ;


        read(newsockfd,user,20);
        usleep(1000);
        read(newsockfd,pass,20);

        if((strcmp(pass,"123") != 0) && (strcmp(user, "tuhin") != 0))
            {
            char auth[2]="1";
            write(newsockfd,auth,2);
            close(newsockfd);
            exit(0);    
        }else{
            char auth[2]="0";
                write(newsockfd,auth,2);
        }

    }
    //End OF Authentication

    //Server NAME
    char S_name[15]="ftp_C-project.";
    usleep(1000);
    write(newsockfd,S_name,15);

    //check Id from client
    system("clear");
    char id[2];
    read(newsockfd,id,2);
    int ch = atoi(id);
    switch(ch)
    {

        case 1:download();
        break;

        case 2:upload();
        break;

        case 3:server_files();
        break;

        case 4:printf("\nDisplayed file contents of Client\n\n");
        break;

        default:printf("Invalid\n");
    }
}//END OF WHILE(1)
    return 0;
}



    int download()
    {
        char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
        n=read(newsockfd,buffer,256);
        if(n<0){
        printf("Error reading from socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    n=access(buffer,F_OK); // Check for validation of file
    switch(n)
    {
    case 0:
        {
        //sends value 0 to char error of client, "File present"
        char id[2]="0";
        write(newsockfd,id,2);

            printf("Client connected successfully\n");
        printf("\nFile requested by the client : %s \n\n", buffer);

        char buf[256] = {'\0'};
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(buffer, "r");
            if(fp == NULL)
            {
                printf("fopen failed : %s \n", strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }else
            {
                printf("Open of file \"%s\" is successful \n", buffer);
        }

        while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL)
        {
            //printf("printing line from the file : %s \n", buf);
            write(newsockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        }
        printf("\nFile Transfer Completed.\n");
        }

    case-1:
        {
        char id[2]="-1";
        write(newsockfd,id,2);
        printf("Download process terminated.\n");
        }
    }
}




    void upload()
    {
        char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  

    // error will store -1 || 0
      char error[256];
      read(newsockfd, error, 256);
      int ch =atoi(error);

    if(ch==0)
    {   
        n=read(newsockfd,buffer,256);
        if(n<0){
        printf("Error reading from socket\n");
        exit(1);
        }

        char mybuf[256];
            FILE *fp = fopen(buffer, "a+");

            while(1)
        {
            n = read(newsockfd, mybuf, sizeof(mybuf));
             if (n <= 0)
            break;
            fputs(mybuf, fp);  
        } 
        printf("\nFile requested by the client to upload: %s \n", buffer);
        printf("\nUpload Complete\n");

    }
    else
    printf("Upload process terminated.\n");
    }


    void server_files()
    {
        char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
        system("ls -l>_");

        char buf[256] = {'\0'};
        FILE *fp = fopen("_", "r");
        while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL)
        {

        write(newsockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));

        }
        system("rm _");
        printf("\nSent file contents of the Server to Client\n");
    }
```

**Client Side:**

```
#include<stdio.h>  
 #include<stdlib.h>  
 #include<sys/types.h>     
 #include<sys/socket.h>  
 #include<netinet/in.h>  
 #include<netdb.h>  
 #include<string.h>  
 #include<unistd.h> 
 #include<errno.h>

    void client_files();
    void server_files();
    void download();
    int upload();

  int sockfd,portno,n,q;  
      char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
      struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;  
      struct hostent *server; 

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
 {  

      if(argc<3)  
      {  
      fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s hostname port\n",argv[0]);  
 exit(1);  
      }  

      portno = atoi(argv[2]);       
      sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);  

      if(sockfd<0)  
      {  
      printf("Error opening socket\n"); 
      exit(0);  
      }  

      bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));//zeroing the sturture  
      server=gethostbyname(argv[1]);  

      if(server==NULL){  
      fprintf(stderr,"Error, no such host\n");  
      exit(0);  
      }  

      serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;  
      bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);  

      serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);  

      if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) <0 )  
      {  
      printf("Error Connecting\n");  
      exit(0); 
      } 

      //Authentication
      system("clear");
      char id[2]="0";
    write(sockfd,id,strlen(id));
      char usr[20]={ '\0' } ;
      char pwsd[20]={ '\0' } ;
      char auth[256]={ '\0' } ;
      system("clear");  
      printf("Authentication!\n");

      printf("User :");
      scanf("%s",usr);
      write(sockfd,usr,strlen(usr));

      char *pswd =getpass("#");
      write(sockfd,pwsd,20);

     usleep(1000);
        read(sockfd,auth,2);
        int x=atoi(auth);
        if(x)
    {
        printf("Access Denied!\nWrong Credentials.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
        }
      //End OF Authentication

      //Fetch name of Server
      char S_name[15];
      system("clear");
        read(sockfd,S_name,15);
        sleep(1);
      printf("Server Name: %s\n",S_name);


      sleep(1);
        printf("\n>>>>Access Granted<<<<\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("1.Download\n2.Upload\n");
    printf("3.List files (Server)\n4.List files (Client)\n");
    int ch;
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch){
    case 1:download();
    break;
    case 2:upload();
    break;
    case 3:server_files();
    break;
    case 4:client_files();
    break;
    default:
    printf("Invalid Input\n");
    }
      return 0;  
 }  



    void download()
    {
    char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
    char id[2]="1";
    write(sockfd,id,strlen(id));

    printf("Enter the filename to download from the server:");  
      scanf("%s", buffer);
      n=write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)); 
      if(n<0){  
      printf("Error writing to socket\n");  
      exit(0); 
      }  

        // error will store -1 || 0
      char error[256];
      read(sockfd, error, 256);
      int ch =atoi(error);
        switch(ch)
        {
      case 0://If file present on server
        {
        printf("Download Initialized \n");

            char mybuf[256];
             FILE *fp = fopen(buffer, "a+");

        while(1)
             {
                n = read(sockfd, mybuf, sizeof(mybuf));
                if (n <= 0)
                break;
            // printf("buf : %s \n", mybuf);
                fputs(mybuf, fp);  
        } 
        sleep(1);

        printf("\nDownload Completed \n\n");
        break;
        }

    case-1://If file not present on server
        printf("\nFile \"%s\" not found.\n",buffer);
        printf("Download process terminated.\n");
        break;
        }
    }



    int upload(){
    char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
    char id[2]="2";
    write(sockfd,id,strlen(id)); 
    printf("Enter the filename to upload to the server:");  
      scanf("%s", buffer);

    n=access(buffer,F_OK);

    switch(n)
    {

    case 0:
        {
            char id[2]="0";
            write(sockfd,id,2);
            usleep(5000);
            n=write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
            usleep(5000);
            if(n<0){  
            printf("Error writing to socket\n");  
            exit(0); 
            } 

            printf("Upload Initialized \n");

            char mybuf[256];
            memset(mybuf, '\0', sizeof(mybuf));
                FILE *fp = fopen(buffer, "r");
            if(fp == NULL)
             {
                    printf("fopen failed : %s \n", strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
             else
                {
                    printf("Open of file \"%s\" is successful \n", buffer);
            }


            while(fgets(mybuf, sizeof(mybuf), fp) != NULL)
            {
                //printf("printing line from the file : %s \n", mybuf);
                write(sockfd, mybuf, sizeof(mybuf));
            }

            printf("\nFile Transfer Completed.\n");
            break;
        }

    case-1:
        {
            char id[2]="-1";
            write(sockfd,id,2);

            printf("\nFile \"%s\" not found.\n",buffer);
            printf("Upload process terminated.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

    void server_files(){
    char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
    char id[2]="3";
    write(sockfd,id,strlen(id));
    int x=0;
    char mybuf[256];
    while(1)
     {
         n = read(sockfd, mybuf, sizeof(mybuf));
        if (n <= 0)
         break;
    if(x!=1){
     printf(" %s ", mybuf); 
    }
    x++;    
    }
     }  


    void client_files(){
    char buffer[256] = {'\0'};  
    char id[2]="4";
    write(sockfd,id,strlen(id));
    system("ls -l");
    }
```

Comment: How you are looping the connection. I just see commented while(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear based on you pasted.  You should paste the exact code that does not work.

But it seems that your while loop starts after the accept, this is not right.  You need to call `accept()` for every new connection:

```
while ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clien))  != -1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You also have to call `close(newsockfd)` when you're done with the connection otherwise you'll leak file descriptors.

Also, you do realize that your server as it is right now can service only one connection at a time.  I assume so but saying just in case :)

Note: you should really not have any call to `system()`.  You should use the UNIX API but that's beyond the scope of your question.